# Trying to use BitsTransfer (Powershell) or bitsadmin to transfer files when booted into WinRE

Tags: powershell, winpe

Trying to use BitsTransfer (Powershell) or bitsadmin to transfer files when booted into WinRE.

I am able to get the file using invoke-webrequest for the same paths. None of the Bits commands give much information other than "The device is not ready".  My searches only return information on Windows update.

I have tried restarting services.

When I run Start-BitsTransfer I get:

VERBOSE: Performing the operation "New" on target "BitsTransfer".
Start-BitsTransfer : The device is not ready.
The device is not ready.
At line:1 char:1

- Start-BitsTransfer "http://...Source...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Start-BitsTransfer], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileNotFoundException,Microsoft.BackgroundIntelligentTransfer.Management.NewBitsTransferCommand
  ```

Get-BitsTransfer command gives me:

get-bitstransfer : The device is not ready.
The device is not ready.
At line:1 char:1

- get-bitstransfer
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-BitsTransfer], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileNotFoundException,Microsoft.BackgroundIntelligentTransfer.Management.GetBitsTransfer
  ```

BitsAdmin.exe gives me:

BITSADMIN version 3.0
BITS administration utility.
(C) Copyright Microsoft Corp.

Unable to connect to BITS - 0x80070015
The device is not ready.

Comment: What is winre?.

Comment: WinRE is the recovery environment for Windows.  It is essentially a more robust WinPE (Preinstallation Environment)

Comment: I don't see a BITS service running.  I can't even start powershell.

Comment: Neither Bits nor PowerShell work natively in WinPE.  You need to inject the components with DISM.  WinRE does support it, but it is a specialized environment that is built into Windows.  I have it modified it so that we can do some more tasks.  I am hoping someone will recognize the error (The device is not ready) and see if I can get past that.

Comment: @eubs, maybe you already figured it out by yourself, but if not, try to add Powershell as already recommended above. Maybe you some additional capabilities as well. 
You can find some more information on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-add-packages--optional-components-reference?view=windows-11